# I'm getting this error in Airflow WEB UI Logs constantly backend postgres? ERROR - Scheduler heartbeat got an exception: (psycopg2.OperationalError)

Tags: postgresql, database-connection, airflow, airflow-scheduler

My airflow is install on kubernetes cluster with 3 nodes and configured with postgres SQL Server, Recently multiple logs of the DAG File is having this error and because of this the job gets delayed by approx 2 hours as it resumes only after approx 2 hours. Why is this happening and how can we fix this?

{logging_mixin.py:95} INFO - [2019-11-19 10:20:07,450] {jobs.py:188} ERROR - Scheduler heartbeat got an exception: (psycopg2.OperationalError) SSL SYSCALL error: Connection timed out
FATAL:  SSL connection is required. Please specify SSL options and retry.
 (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)

Comment: Have you tried specifying the ssl mode for the db connection string in the airflow config file?  e.g. `sql_alchemy_conn = postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@127.0.0.1/airflow?sslmode=verify-full`

Comment: Hi, In my current airflow config file,my current config is sql_alchemy_conn = sqlite:////usr/local/airflow/airflow.db and other details are # The encoding for the databases
sql_engine_encoding = utf-8

# If SqlAlchemy should pool database connections.
sql_alchemy_pool_enabled = True

# The SqlAlchemy pool size is the maximum number of database connections
# in the pool. 0 indicates no limit.
sql_alchemy_pool_size = 10

Also just want to highlight multiple jobs have been running from a month and only in few logs we see the error. Thanks, I'm not able to understand.

Comment: Perhaps it's the postgresql connection definition for one of your tasks that needs adjustment (adding {"sslmode": "verify-full"} to the extra section of the connection definition)?  Do you have a single worker node or multiple?

Comment: I have a kubernetes cluster where we have 3 nodes currently. There is 1 worker pod.  So you mean to say we need to change in the config file sql_alchemy_conn

Comment: just to give you a small info in my config file, they were like environment variables sql_alchemy_conn , So i check the variables and In the connection string I am not specifying sslmode=verify-full currently, so should I specify it and will it resolve this issue?  Thanks

Comment: I have zero experience with Kubernetes ;).  The error you posted references psycopg2, which is a "driver" for PostgreSql.  So I was thinking that you must have a postgresql connection defined someplace.  I'd try to find that PostgreSql connection and try adding {"sslmode": "verify-full"} to the extra section of the connection definition (in the Airflow web interface).

Comment: Okay thanks, just to summarize if we add that in the connection string then connection to postgres sql will be more stable and we will see these errors rarely. Am I right? Thanks

Comment: Hopefully ;) - give it a try.